# Update Google Play services notification making tests fail on Firebase Test Lab devices

Tags: android, android-espresso, firebase-test-lab

When running an Espresso test in Firebase Test Labs I sometimes get this notification showing that the Google Play services need to be updated.

[image]

This results in some failing tests because some tests try to click elements below this notification. Are there any easy solutions for this?

Comment: You should contact Firebase support if you see this happen.  They can pass that feedback on to Test Lab engineering.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Answer (score 1):

This notification can be displayed on devices when the version of the Play Store app is older than the version of the Play Services library that your app is using.

The best way to fix this is not to depend on the latest versions of the library, but rather use an older one if possible.